# multithreading in java is not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to use multithreading in java to check for prime numbers in a certain range. Depending on many cores my processor has, I need to create threads to do the work. I've 4 cores so I've created four threads. The problem here is that the threads are not alternating while doing their work. What happens is first thread starts and does the work, then the second one starts after the first is done, etc. If I use the sleep method, then I can see the threads alternating but that doesn't seem like multithreading to me. Is there an explanation to that in Java? are they actually working simultaneously under the hood but I can't see it?
Thanks in advance, and here's my code:

```
package multithreading;

 import java.util.*;

 public class MultithreadingV2{

static ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
static int counter = 0;
    public static synchronized void primeChecker(int rangeStart, int rangeEnd) throws InterruptedException{

        for(int x = rangeStart; x < rangeEnd; x++){

            int temp;
            boolean isPrime=true;

            int numm = x;
            Thread.sleep(50);
            for(int i=2;i<=numm/2;i++)
            {
               temp=numm%i;
               if(temp==0)
               {
                   isPrime=false;                      
                   break;

               }
            }

            if(isPrime){
               System.out.println("thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
               System.out.println(numm + " is a Prime Number");
               primes.add(numm);
            }
        }

    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

    int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    System.out.println("CPU cores: " + processors);

    int rangeStart = 2;
    int rangeEnd = 1000;

    Thread t1 = null;
    for(int x = 1; x <= processors; x++){
        counter = x;
        t1 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                if(counter == 1)
                    try {
                        primeChecker(rangeStart, rangeEnd);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                else if(counter == 2)
                    try {
                        primeChecker(rangeEnd + 1, rangeEnd * 2);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                else if(counter == 3)
                    try {
                        primeChecker((rangeEnd * 2) + 1, rangeEnd * 3);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                else if(counter == 4)
                    try {
                        primeChecker((rangeEnd * 3) + 1, rangeEnd * 4);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }

        };

        t1.start();

//          t1.join();
    }

    System.out.println("prime size: " + primes.size());

    long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(totalTime);
}


}
```

Comment: _"multithreading in java is not working as expected"_ really means your expectations of how it should work are incorrect.  Threads are completely independent unless you take steps to synchronize them.  Why would you expect them to "alternate"?

Comment: `static synchronized` hm

Comment: I get the feeling there's an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) lurking in here.  You are going to great lengths to make the program behave according to some incorrect expectations, and it looks much more complex than it needs to be.  But I can't figure out what you're actually trying to do, or what your expectation is.

Comment: @JimGarrison doesn't multithreading mean working in parallel? thanks for your comment

Comment: @user2066392: you need to understand how synchronization works, I think.

Comment: Yes. But why do you have `sleep(50)` in there? Are you trying to have 4 threads concurrently finding primes but then have them come out in ascending sequence?

Comment: The key word is "expected".  It's your expectations that need adjusting, not Java multi-threading.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do, run 4 threads concurrently. Then print out the result whenever a thread does its work. One solution posted here by @Stephen C seems to work!! I made the  "primeChecker" method non-static, created an object that calls "primeChecker". The order of threads printing the results changes every time I run the program!!

Comment: @user2066392 Multithreading does not enforce "round robining" at ever line of code. The CPU (VM) decides WHEN the threads get time, and guarantees no 'interwoven' or 'back-and-forth' functionality. If the CPU is fast enough it may complete one thread fully before it even starts the other thread's work. That's fine. Like duffymo said, don't try to expect the ordering of things in separate threads "relative to each other thread" becuase if you have a need for that you need to look up "thread synchronization". And so yes it could run 'differently every time' . Threading is not deterministic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `primeChecker` is a `static synchronized` method.  This means that when you call it, you acquire a lock that prevents any other thread from calling the method until your call completes.  In other words, the calculation will be effectively single-threaded; i.e. no parallelism.

Basically, you need to figure out a better way to synchronize the access / updates to your shared state.  One that doesn't prevent other threads from making any progress.

Hint: you only need to synchronize the places where the threads are actually sharing state.

Comment: so i basically delete the keyword "static" and synchronize". Then created an object that call the "primeChecker" method. I believe it is working now because I see the threads printing result in different order each time I run the program. THANKS!!

Comment: I guess that the point isn't you actually to do it but understand why the "static synchronized" combo killed you concurrence.

Comment: Note that *just* deleting the `static` and `synchronized` is NOT a correct solution.  If you do that, you have threads sharing a data structure without proper synchronization.  The result is program that violates the requirements of the Java Memory Model, and gives unpredictable results in some circumstances; i.e. a dreaded Heisenbug!  In my answer, I said *"... you need to figure out a better way to synchronize the access / updates to your shared state."*  I did NOT say "get rid of the synchronization".

Comment: @Stephen C I did some research and you are 100% right about the synchronization part, and if I had a data structure accessed by all threads then I will get a wrong final result. In my case, I'm not trying to access any data structure, all I'm trying to do is to give each thread a function that does prime checking for a range of numbers and only print prime numbers. The range of numbers is different for each thread.

Comment: @user2066392 - Even in this case there is a shared data structure.  The worker threads are adding primes to a shared list, and the main thread is then reading it.  That requires synchronization.